# How to get the average price based on multiple room prices

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have table called room_prices that store different prices according to the date specified. Here's the sample data.

```
id  room_id date_from   date_to     price
1   1                               3500.00
25  1       7/28/2012   7/29/2012   3600.00
27  1       8/24/2012   8/27/2012   3000.00
49  1       11/12/2012  11/16/2012  4000.00
```

The first row is the default price of room 1 (room_id = 1).

When guest reserve a room, the system will first look at the prices on room_prices table. If the date reserved by guest was found on the table it will get the price according to the date selected and not the default price.

Ex.

If the guest reserved a room from 11/10/2012 to 11/11/2012 then the price should be 3,500.
If the guest reserved a room from 11/12/2012 to 11/14/2012 then the price should be 4,000.

If the guest reserved a room from 11/10/2012 to 11/13/2012 then the average price should be 3750. See table below:

```
11/10/2012  3500
11/11/2012  3500
11/12/2012  4000
11/13/2012  4000
            3750
```

So my question is if there is a single SQL code to get the average price.

update:

I tried this sql to no avail:

```
SELECT avg(price) as avg_price
                        FROM lf_rooms_prices
                        WHERE room_id = 1
                        AND ((DATE_FORMAT(date_from, '%m/%d/%Y') >= '11/10/2012' 
                        AND DATE_FORMAT(date_from, '%m/%d/%Y') < '11/10/2012') 
                        OR (DATE_FORMAT(date_to, '%m/%d/%Y') > '11/13/2012' 
                        AND DATE_FORMAT(date_to, '%m/%d/%Y') <= '11/13/2012'))
```

btw, I'm using codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

There's `AVG()` function, so to get average price your query should look like this:

```
SELECT AVG(`price`) FROM `room_prices` GROUP BY `room_id`
```

See docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg). And of course you can add WHERE to the query to narrow data set you want the average value of:

```
SELECT AVG(`price`) FROM `room_prices` WHERE <CONDITIONS> GROUP BY `room_id`
```

**EDIT:**

Full query:

```
SELECT AVG(`price`) FROM `room_prices` 
    WHERE `room_id` = 1
          AND ((DATE_FORMAT(date_from, '%m/%d/%Y') >= '11/10/2012' 
          AND DATE_FORMAT(date_from, '%m/%d/%Y') < '11/10/2012') 
          OR (DATE_FORMAT(date_to, '%m/%d/%Y') > '11/13/2012' 
          AND DATE_FORMAT(date_to, '%m/%d/%Y') <= '11/13/2012'))
GROUP BY `room_id`
```

The key is to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: This is an average of all prices for room 1 in the room_prices table, but it's not what the op was looking for.

Comment: You can add `WHERE` to the query to narrow data set you want the average value of.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com what is the WHERE clause?

Comment: Updated again - I over-smarted myself previously and accidentally omitted `room_id` in `WHERE`

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com it does not return any value.

Comment: how can this be an answer to my question? did you guys try it before rating? If the guest reserved a room from 11/10/2012 to 11/13/2012 then how can I get the average price of 3750?